# How to compare text documents for each category within a data frame

Tags: r, machine-learning, text-mining, word-frequency

I am trying to count terms in text within each category and then compare the result between the categories in a data frame. 
In my data frame there are two columns: **IdName** for category id and **X** for text field. See attachment.
As I am putting **x** into Corpus, normalize and create tdm, I am losing the IdName to determine to which category this term belongs to.

[My Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUHKI.png)

```
docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(data$x))

tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs, control = list(bounds = list(global = c(1, Inf))))

term.freq <- rowSums(as.matrix(tdm))
df.tdm <- data.frame(term = names(term.freq), freq = term.freq)
```

Once I get the top frequent terms how can I identify which term belongs to which category to compare between them? Or do I need to run term frequency for each category as a separate data frame? If so, then how do I compare each category then?

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please edit your question to input your data frame inline as text. Links to images may break and also make it harder for others trying to work with your problem.

Comment: 1) The tdm is in the same order as your df so you can set the colnames of your tdm to the rownames of your df. The second part of your post is unclear. Do you want to know which terms are most frequent for each category or which category the most frequent terms occur?

Comment: @emilliman5 I am trying just to get frequency of each word within each category and then compare the results between categories.